# Remove/deactivate CSRF token

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms, csrf-token

By default, validating CSRF token in Flask-WTF does not disable it, it remains activate and usable until it expires. I want to disable csrf token that I already verified with `validate_csrf()`. Something like this simplified

```
def register_form():
    response_data = { "register_form_csrf_token" : generate_csrf() }
    # ...
    # code
    # ...
    return make_response(jsonify(response_data)), HTTPStatus.OK.value
def register_submit():
    # the below question throws error when csrf token invalid/session token is wrong
    validate_csrf(request.form['register_form_csrf_token'])
    # the function below does not exist, just how i imagined it will be
    remove_csrf(request.form['register_form_csrf_token'])
    # ...
    # code
    # ...
```

How do i achieve this ? i tried gooling, reading https://flask-wtf.readthedocs.io/en/0.15.x/csrf/, and reading the docs, but havent found the method to do it